# How to populate JQuery auto-complete combobox dynamically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using the [JQuery UI Autocomplete combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox).

I have a simple select like this:

```
<select id="myselect" class="combobox">    
<option value="" ></option>
</select>"
```

When the page loads I call this:

```
$('.combobox').combobox();
```

What I need to do is populate the combobox after the page has loaded. This sounds like a trivial task but I've been banging my head against the wall in the last day trying to get this to work.

Even when I try a simple append like this:

```
$("#myselect").append('<option value="value1">text 1</option>')
```

the value does not appear in the combobox. The above call must be wrong but I don't know how else to append values to the combobox.

Please show me a way to do this.

Your help is much appreciated

this is the source code for my combobox.js file:

```
(function ($) {
$.widget("ui.combobox", {

    _create: function () {
        var select = this.element;
        select = this.element;
        var watermark = "Please select a restaurant...";
        select.hide();

        // process select options into an array
        var opts = new Array();

        $('option', select).each(function (index) {
            var opt = new Object();
            opt.value = $(this).val();
            if ($(this).text() != "") {
                opt.label = $(this).text();
                opts[opts.length] = opt;
            }
        });

        // set up input text element
        var input = $("<input class='combo_input' type='text'>");

        input.insertAfter(select);
        input.autocomplete({
            source: opts,
            delay: 0,
            change: function (event, ui) {
                if (!ui.item) {
                    // user didn't select an option, but what they typed may still match
                    var enteredString = $(this).val();
                    var stringMatch = false;
                    for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
                        if (opts[i].label.toLowerCase() == enteredString.toLowerCase()) {
                            select.val(opts[i].value);// update (hidden) select
                            //$(this).val(opts[i].label);// corrects any incorrect case
                            //opts[i].css("border", "1px solid red");
                            stringMatch = true;

                            // Trigger the custom changed event
                            self._trigger("changed", event, {
                                value: select.val()
                            });
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!stringMatch) {
                        // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                        $(':selected', select).text("");
                        $(this).val($(':selected', select).text()).addClass('watermark');

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                select.val(ui.item.value);// update (hidden) select
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                if ($(this).val() == watermark) {
                    input.addClass('watermark');
                    imgbt.addClass("invisibility");
                }
                else {
                    input.removeClass('watermark');
                    imgbt.removeClass("invisibility");
                }
                // Trigger the selected event
                ui.item.selected = true;
                self._trigger("selected", event, {
                    value: ui.item.value
                });
                return false;
            },
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                if (event.which === 38 || event.which === 40) {
                    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                    return false;
                }

            },
            // stop parent form from being while menu is open
            open: function (event, ui) {
                input.attr("menustatus", "open");

            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                input.attr("menustatus", "closed");
            },
            autoFocus: true,
            minLength: 0
        });

        input.addClass("ui-widget");

        // initialise text with what's currently selected

        if ($(':selected', select).val() == "") {
            input.val(watermark).addClass('watermark')
        } else {
            input.val($(':selected', select).text()).removeClass('watermark');
        }
        input.attr('title', input.val());


        // lost focus status            

        input.blur(function (e) {
            if (input.val() == "") {
                input.val(watermark).addClass('watermark');
                imgbt.addClass("invisibility");
            }
            else {
                input.removeClass('watermark')
                imgbt.removeClass("invisibility");
            }
        });

        //clear text when user clicks in text input             
        input.click(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == watermark) {
                $(this).removeClass('watermark').val("");
                imgbt.addClass("invisibility");
            } else {
                imgbt.removeClass("invisibility");
            }

        });


        // over-ride form submit, so it cant submit if the menu is open
        input.attr("menustatus", "closed");
        var form = $(input).parents('form:first');
        $(form).submit(function (e) {
            return (input.attr('menustatus') == 'closed');
        });

        var imgbt = $("<button type=\"button\">&nbsp;</button>");
        imgbt.addClass('clear_bt').addClass('btn');
        if (input.val() == watermark) { imgbt.addClass('invisibility') }
        else { imgbt.removeClass('invisibility') }
        imgbt.insertAfter(input);

        // Clear all the keywords
        imgbt.click(function (e) {
            input.val('');
            $("body").focus();
            $(this).addClass('invisibility');
            $("#rcbRestaurant").val("");
        });
        imgbt.blur(function (e) {
            input.blur();
        });

        // set up button for fake 'select'

        var btn = $("<button>&nbsp;</button>");
        btn.attr("tabIndex", -1);
        btn.attr("title", "Select your option");
        btn.addClass("combobox_bt");
        btn.insertAfter(imgbt);
        if (select.hasClass('disabled')) {
            input.addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            btn.addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        if (select.hasClass('error')) {
            input.addClass('error').focus();
            btn.addClass('error').focus();
        } else { input.removeClass('error'); btn.removeClass('error'); }

        if (select.attr('autofocus') == 'autofocus') {
            input.focus();
            btn.focus();
        }

        btn.button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s "
            },
            text: false
        });
        btn.removeClass("ui-corner-all");
        btn.addClass("ui-corner-right ui-button-icon");
        btn.click(function () {
            btn.focus();
            input.click();
            //event.preventDefault();
            // close if already visible
            if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                input.autocomplete("close");
                return false; // return false, so form isn't automatically submitted
            }
            // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete("search", "");
            input.focus();
            return false; // return false, so form isn't automatically submitted
        });

        // add some styles
        btn.css("z-index", "1");
        btn.css("display", "inline");
        btn.css("padding", 0);
        $('span.ui-button-text', btn).css("padding", 0);

        // for testing
        /*
        autocomplete: function(value) {
            this.element.val(value);
            this.input.val(value);
        }
        */
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/n7xuD/)***

The demo you link, and the `combobox` you call, show a custom implementation of "what autocomplete can be". In order to use this functionality, you have to code your own combobox. This is the point of that demo. So for you, you *must* implement your own combobx widget in order to use its functionality. There is no "combobox" which comes standard with jQuery UI, only autocomplete. Note that you will get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'combobox'

Without using the custom implementation. Basically, you should just copy paste the widget and then use it or modify it for your own uses.

```
(function( $ ) {
$.widget( "custom.combobox", {
  _create: function() {
    this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
      .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
      .insertAfter( this.element );

    this.element.hide();
    this._createAutocomplete();
    this._createShowAllButton();
  },

  _createAutocomplete: function() {
    var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
      value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

    this.input = $( "<input>" )
      .appendTo( this.wrapper )
      .val( value )
      .attr( "title", "" )
      .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
      .autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 0,
        source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
      })
      .tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
      });

    this._on( this.input, {
      autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.item.option.selected = true;
        this._trigger( "select", event, {
          item: ui.item.option
        });
      },

      autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
    });
  },

  _createShowAllButton: function() {
    var input = this.input,
      wasOpen = false;

    $( "<a>" )
      .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
      .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
      .tooltip()
      .appendTo( this.wrapper )
      .button({
        icons: {
          primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
        },
        text: false
      })
      .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
      .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
      .mousedown(function() {
        wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
      })
      .click(function() {
        input.focus();

        // Close if already visible
        if ( wasOpen ) {
          return;
        }

        // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
        input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
      });
  },

  _source: function( request, response ) {
    var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
    response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
      var text = $( this ).text();
      if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
        return {
          label: text,
          value: text,
          option: this
        };
    }) );
  },

  _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {

    // Selected an item, nothing to do
    if ( ui.item ) {
      return;
    }

    // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
    var value = this.input.val(),
      valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
      valid = false;
    this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
      if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
        this.selected = valid = true;
        return false;
      }
    });

    // Found a match, nothing to do
    if ( valid ) {
      return;
    }

    // Remove invalid value
    this.input
      .val( "" )
      .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
      .tooltip( "open" );
    this.element.val( "" );
    this._delay(function() {
      this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
    }, 2500 );
    this.input.data( "ui-autocomplete" ).term = "";
  },

  _destroy: function() {
    this.wrapper.remove();
    this.element.show();
  }
});
})( jQuery );
```

with styling

```
.custom-combobox {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}
.custom-combobox-toggle {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin-left: -1px;
 padding: 0;
 /* support: IE7 */
 height: 1.7em;
 top: 0.1em;
}
.custom-combobox-input {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0.3em;
}
```

---

Doing all of this will allow you to simply use

```
$("#myselect").append('<option value="value1">text 1</option>');
$('#myselect').combobox();
$("#myselect").append('<option value="value2">text 2</option>');
```

Comment: Thanks Travis J. I'm not sure what you mean. I HAVE downloaded it and included in my project, otherwise how I could use it? I have made some  modifications to it as well, but cannot do what you mentioned in your last lines. However, there are some differences between my version (apart from my changes) with the version you have posted here. I'll try your version and if it works, might have to add my changes to it. But I'm just curious why mine does not work.

Comment: @seemorgh - It was hard to derive the exact situation which was occurring when you first posted your question as it lacked your source code. I see that you have edited in your source code and will post an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) in the past to accomplish this.  Might that work for you?

Comment: Hi Wefx. Thanks for your quick response. I can try it out but the JQuery UI combobox is what my client have been using and they would rather keep it for consistency. Is there any way to easily achieve what I am asking? It shouldn't be that difficult!

Answer (score 0):

use jquery ui autocomplete, its much easier

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. This IS what I am using. I am using the autocomplete combobox (as the link in my question).

Comment: You shouldnt be calling combobox to create the widget, instead .autocomplete, There are demos on the page, tried them?

Comment: According to the source code in the demo (view source link at the bottom of the page - see the link in my question) the call to attach the combobox is this: $( "#combobox" ).combobox();

Comment: try this

    $("#myselect").html('<option value="value1">text 1</option>');