# How to trigger the select function when the value is selected after the tab is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a combo box that enables the autocomplete function.

The project that I am working on currently uses the same code that is mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21414209/3811265).

I have modified the code to select the value on the tab pressed if it matched the exact text in the select.

In the source, I called this function.

```
this._addTabAndReturnListener(matchedOptions);
```

and I have implemented `_addTabAndReturnListener` as:

```
_addTabAndReturnListener: function(options) {
  var self = this;
  var element = this.element;
  var input = this.input[0];
  this.input.off('keydown.first'); // Disable listener from previous call
  this.input.on('keydown.first', function(e) {
    var keycode = e.which;
    if (keycode == 9 || keycode == 13) // If tab key pressed
      if (options.length == 1) {
        var result = null;
        element.children("option").each(function() {
          if ($(this).text() == options[0].value)
            result = this;
        })
        if (result != null)
          input.value = $(result).text();

        $(this).attr("title", input.value + " matched").tooltip("open");
        input.dispatchEvent(new Event("select"));

      }
  });
},
```

I wanted to trigger the select function when the value is selected after the tab is pressed, but not able to do so.

Normally when a value is selected from the dropdown the following functions have been triggered, and the alert is displayed. But it is not working on the tab pressed.

```
$('#myselect').combobox({
  select: function(event, ui) {
    alert(event.target);
  }
});
```

What could be the solution for this?

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eg2mxL9v/)

Comment: Dispatch the _correct_ event, maybe? You are trying to dispatch `new Event("select")`, but the two events this plugin defines, appear to be called `autocompleteselect` and `autocompletechange`. And perhaps you should rather be using https://api.jquery.com/trigger/ for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by adding a trigger.

```
$(this).trigger("tabOnChange", result);
```

and define a new event, called `tabOnChange`

```
tabOnChange: function(event, opt) {
  opt.selected = true;
  this._trigger("select", event, {
    item: opt
  });
},
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gnwLpau/):